# How to make VSCode integrated terminal run the same Conda Python interpreter as Terminal.app?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I have miniconda installed with automatic `base` environment activation using `/usr/bash` in the `Terminal.app`. When I first open `Terminal.app` and run `python` the correct interpreter inside the `base` environment is run, say `Python3.8`.

Inside VSCode (without necessarily having opened it using something like `code .`) I have the integrated terminal, which opens `bash` as expected. The prompt is in fact the same as when I open `Terminal.app`: say `(base) $`. However, if I run `python`, MacOS's system `Python2.7` is activated, instead of conda's Python.

The only way I've found to actually run the Python interpreter from within conda's `base` environment, automatically and consistently with `Terminal.app`, is to run `conda deactivate`, then `conda activate` again. In fact, if I search for Python executables in the environment, by typing `python` then clicking tab from within the first initialization of the integrated bash terminal, the results include executables that are only available within conda's `base` environment, which leads me to believe that I have that environment truly activated.

Furthermore, if I use the Select Python Interpreter in VSCode and choose the `base` environment, when I activate the integrated terminal it will run `source ~/opt/miniconda3/bin/activate base`, and even then if I run `python`, conda's Python interpreter is ignored, and I will get MacOS's `Python2.7`.

I have tried setting both `python.pythonPath` and `python.condaPath` options to the default `base` Python in `settings.json`, with no success.

Somehow VSCode is activating conda's environment, as expected, but is overwriting the `python` command to the system's default `Python2.7`, instead of the environment's default `Python3.8`. How do I get VSCode to run the Python interpreter consistently with the conda's `base` environment, like `Terminal.app` does?

Comment: Please select this [conda environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments) in the lower left corner of VS Code and use the shortcut key "Ctrl+Shift+`" to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment. In addition, you could also activate it with the command "conda activate base".

Comment: I commented in paragraphs 3 and 4 of the question that 1) I can select the conda environment like you suggested, but it still doesn't automatically run the Python interpreter of that environment. I need to deactivate and then activate the environment manually. 2) By deactivating and activating I get the desired result, but I don't want to have to do this every time I start an integrated terminal, which is the point of this question. The correct Python interpreter should be selected automatically at the moment I start the integrated terminal.

Comment: This is weird, Have you tried to create other new conda environments in VS Code?